# My FTC motor is continously running, any ideas?

Tags: java, robotics

This is my program. Why does it keeps moving, instead of stopping? I don't see any clear issues, and the motor just continues turning without stopping.

```
package org.firstinspires.ftc.teamcode.drive.auto;

import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.Autonomous;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.LinearOpMode;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.DcMotor;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.DcMotorSimple;

@Autonomous(name="EncoderTestOneThousand", group="Autonomous")
public class EncoderTestOneThousand extends LinearOpMode {
    private DcMotor main;
    private int mainPos;

    @Override
    public void runOpMode() {
        main = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "main");
        main.setMode(DcMotor.RunMode.STOP_AND_RESET_ENCODER);
        main.setDirection(DcMotorSimple.Direction.REVERSE);
        mainPos = 0;
        waitForStart();
        drive (100, 0.5);
    }

    private void drive(int mainTarget, double speed) {
        mainPos += mainTarget;
        main.setTargetPosition(mainPos);
        main.setMode(DcMotor.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);
        main.setPower(speed);
        while (opModeIsActive() && main.isBusy()) {
            idle();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to remove and add brackets, and still had the same result. I've double checked it all and don't see any reasons it won't stop movement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
private void drive(int mainTarget, double speed) {
  mainPos += mainTarget;
  main.setTargetPosition(mainPos);
  main.setMode(DcMotor.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);
  main.setPower(speed);
  while (opModeIsActive() && main.isBusy()) {
    idle();
  }
  main.setPower(0); // Stop the motor here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you mean that the motor continues to run until the autonomous timer expires or the program is terminated with the driver station?

If your motor is wired backwards (power and encoder are going opposite directions), the motor will continue to run because it never (within FTC match time) makes it to the target position. This is like trying to go from the Great Lakes to the Gulf of Mexico by flying North! You're taking the long way...

Another possibility is that the encoder connector is plugged in backwards (if you are using a level shifter). This will result in the encoder counts being stuck on a fixed value (typically close to 0).

You can print the current position and the target position inside the while loop, using a telemetry command. This will help you determine if it is a hardware problem.